# Cant get Popup view controller to work on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, popover

So I have a Popup view controller that works on my iPhone put not my iPhone
for example

**iPad:**

[image]

**iPhone:**

[image]

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

**Code:**

```
self.imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    //self.imgPicker.allowsImageEditing = YES;
    self.imgPicker.delegate = self;
    self.imgPicker.sourceType = 
 UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;




locations=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"BOSTON",@"CHICAGO",@"DALLAS",@"DC",@"ORLANDO",@"PHILLY",@"VEGAS",@"NEWYORK",@"LA",@"SANFRAN",@"REPAIR", @"SUBRENTAL",@"MULTIPLE", nil];

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
    [self buildPopover];

} else
    [self buildActionsheet];
```

Comment: Have you checked that you are not missing constraints for iPhone ?
Make sure that you are not creating constraints only for Regular/Regular in the Storyboard.

Comment: I don't see where I check this

Comment: in the size inspector in the storyboard